# SQL SELECT from 4 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following 4 tables:

```
Customer: (List of all customers)
-customer_id
-name
-address

Book: (List of all books)
-ISBN
-version
-title
-category_name
-author

Author: (List of all authors)
-author_id
-name

Loan: (List of all borrowed books )
-customer_id
-ISBN
-copy_id
-lending_date
-return_date
```

How do I display all customers that borrowed a book that was written by a specific author (i.e. `name` from `author`)?

Comment: I think you should edit your question and show your attempts to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `INNER JOIN` to achive this:

```
SELECT c.* FROM Customer c
INNER JOIN Author a ON a.name = 'AUTHOR NAME'
INNER JOIN Book b ON b.author = a.author_id
INNER JOIN Loan l ON l.customer_id = c.customer_id && l.ISBN = b.ISBN;
```

Comment: assuming Book.author = Author.author_id

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Book.author = Author.author_id

```
SELECT      Customer.name   
FROM        Customer
INNER JOIN  Loan ON Loan.customer_id = Customer.customer_id
INNER JOIN  Author ON Author.author_id = Book.author
INNER JOIN  Book ON Book.ISBN=Loan.ISBN
WHERE       Author.name = 'Author'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.customer_id, c.name, c.address
FROM Customer c
INNER JOIN Author a ON a.name = 'AUTHOR_NAME'
INNER JOIN Book b ON b.author = a.author_id
INNER JOIN Loan l ON l.customer_id = c.customer_id && l.ISBN = b.ISBN;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy. Just do like this:

```
SELECT l.customer_id, c.name
FROM Loan l
JOIN Customer c
ON l.customer_id = c.customer_id
JOIN Book b
ON l.ISBN = b.ISBN
JOIN Author a
ON b.author =a.author_id
WHERE a.name = "William Shakespeare"
```